# I have problem with math display in LYX

Tags: lyx

I wrote equation but when I click out It is changed.

How to solve it please?

BEFORE

[image]

AFTER

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you've turned on the instant preview (Tools --> Preferences --> Look&Feel --> Display), but that this particular equation doesn't render.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. So how can I fix it. I put the preference panel in the question

Comment: I have no idea what could cause the preview of that particular equation not to render, but you can always turn off previewing of equations.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. Thanks ever so much. It works by the only turn off the LYX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To summarize comments:)

Your problem comes from the instant preview feature of LyX, which renders equations and other things with LaTeX and creates a PNG that is displayed instead of the default view. For some reason the preview isn't updated, or shows the wrong equation, in this particular case. I don't know why that happens. It's possible that forcing a re-rendering, by making a small change in the equation, would fix it.

If all else fails, you could turn off the instant preview feature, by going to Tools --> Preferences --> Look&Feel --> Display, and selecting either **Off** or **No math** from the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. For me reconfiguring tools (tools>reconfigure) did the trick.